# How can I add a scroll bar on a component using the "React Zoom Pan Pinch" library?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, scrollbar, zooming

Is there a way to add a scroll bar to a component that is using the [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) library? One solution I've tried was using the 'wrapperStyle' component

```
wrapperStyle{{maxHeight:'1000px',overflow: showScroll ? 'scroll':'hidden'}}
```

Basically, what I did here was have a state called `showScroll` that would be set to true if the scale state is greater than 1, which is the initial value, which I get from the [useTransformEffect](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/hooks-usetransformeffect--page) hook that's provided. So when the user would zoom in, `showScroll` would be set to true. The issue is is that with the scroll bar added, im not able to scroll up to the top of the image. I am however, able to drag it to where I can see the top of the image.